# Android 9 Patch - 'bottom' area not showing?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, nine-patch

Am running into something that I have spent hours trying to get working. I have tried searching but what stumbles me is how to search a resolution for this as it is a strange and apparently not-so-common issue?

All I want is to be able to stretch a 'dash of paint' vertically using the y-axis scalable area marked as a single pixel on the left. My 9patch file is below:

[image]

I have gotten this to HALF-work as can be seen (ignore the top horizontal line, this is a separate imageview):

[image]

As you can see, I am missing what I call the 'Non-scalable end' which is basically the static part of the 9patch file (unmarked on left y-axis scalable area)

The code in the layout is simple:

```
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/repeater"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/PlayersList"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/PlayersList"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/repeater" />
```

(file is named repeater.9.png and stored in res/drawable-xhdpi)

Note: For some reason this works exactly as required in the 9-patch tool, but doesn't seem to work in eclipse (earlier screenshot):
[image]

Comment: `stored in res/drawable-xhdpi`... why? normally, you'd store it in the stored in `res/drawable` default folder, since is not resolution dependent. Or even into the `res/drawable-nodpi` folder.

Comment: I am seeking to have multiple resolutions of this image. As you can see, the 'width' of the 'splatter' is fixed therefore technically this is not resolution dependent.

Comment: I see. Anyway, taht image didn't render well in my draw9patch tool (it was too "fat" horizontally). I made a new one that repeats the upper part a bit and just stretches that part horizonatally. I also moved the pixel for vertical stretch accordingly. Didn't test it in my emulator, but in the draw9patch tool it works (now it seems a "reversed L")...

Comment: Correct, this seems to work fine in the draw9patch tool, Will update my question with this. However, not working in Eclipse even though I am not having issues with other 9patch images

Comment: @Vyger : 9 patch are still density dependent. It makes sense to want different nine-patches for different screen densities.

Comment: Yes, I understood the first time. It makes perfect sense. Let me recreate the one I did at the office and try it into some emulators...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the  effect you were looking for ?

I have attached images for all drawables let me know if it worked.
You can use http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html
to generate 9 patch images instead of making it form default tools.

[image]

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_example"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]